# How can I remove the drop shadow from a ComboBox DropDown in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, dropdown, dropshadow

I searched everywhere and tried everything I know, but can't seem to find a way to get rid of that CS_DROPSHADOW embedded in the DropDown popup from the ComboBox control.

This is how it looks now:

[image]

And this is how I want it to look:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Update:
I tried every combination of properties and haven't managed to work around it.
How they're set now:

DropDownStyle = DropDownList

FlatStyle = Flat

DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed

And this is what DrawItem is implemented:

```
if (sender is ComboBox cbx)
{
    e.DrawBackground();

    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat
        {
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center + 1,
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        };

        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gainsboro), e.Bounds);
        else
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(cbx.BackColor), e.Bounds);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(cbx.Items[e.Index].ToString(), cbx.Font, new SolidBrush(cbx.ForeColor), e.Bounds, sf);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set it to "flat" it shouldnt drop a shadow

Comment: The class name of the ListControl is `ComboLBox`...

Comment: IMHO Winforms was made to provide a consistent look & feel across all applications. Thous such details can't really be changed. If you need more control about look & feel you should maybe switch to WPF or create your complete own user control that paints itself in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this, but it is possible to remove the shadow with WinAPI calls + reflection. I haven't seen any property that would allow me to access the drop down window, so I used reflection to get it. I suppose the handle is a short lived object and so is hidden from user. In any case, once you get the handle it is possible to change the window class style with SetClassLongPtr32 function (you may need to use a different version of this function for 64-bit, check documentation).

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestComboBox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.DropDown += ComboBox1_DropDown;
        }

        private void ComboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fieldInfo = comboBox1.GetType().GetField("dropDownHandle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var dropDownHandle = (IntPtr)fieldInfo.GetValue(comboBox1);

            const uint CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;
            const int GCL_STYLE = -26;
            uint currentWindowClassStyle = GetClassLongPtr32(new HandleRef(comboBox1, dropDownHandle), GCL_STYLE);
            uint expectedWindowClassStyle = currentWindowClassStyle & (~CS_DROPSHADOW);
            SetClassLongPtr32(new HandleRef(comboBox1, dropDownHandle), GCL_STYLE, expectedWindowClassStyle);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClassLong")]
        public static extern uint GetClassLongPtr32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetClassLong")]
        public static extern uint SetClassLongPtr32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);
    }
}
```

As a side note, I would rather use WPF to style UI controls. It has powerful tools that allow you to change the visual appearance to whatever you like.